# gen_bridge_metadata and the iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos

Is it possible to run gen_bridge_metadata on iPhone frameworks? I keep running into the problem of gen_bridge_metadata not using my preprocessor defines...

So a call like this...

```
IPHONE_SDK=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk
gen_bridge_metadata -c '-I$IPHONE_SDK/usr/include -DTARGET_OS_IPHONE' --framework "$IPHONE_SDK/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework"
```

... will just ignore the TARGET_OS_IPHONE define and try including some MAC_OS files.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Ignoring TARGET_ OS_IPHONE will get you nowhere (as far as I know.)

You can try a third party workaround, [mobileOrchard](http://mobileorchard.com) looks into different ones, but I don't think you're getting anywhere. :(